# How do i write an excel formular that can work either way?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to write an excel formula that can compute commission charged using simple interest rate. The fields will be:

1. Amount
2. Percentage
3. Commission charged

How do i write a formula that can provide answers to any field once the other two fields have been completed?

Comment: Using IF and ISBLANK. Note, you cannot get the answer in the empty field though.

Comment: If you want to a cell to be both a user entered value or the result of a calculation then you're probably going to have to resort to some VBA - as the act of entering a value will delete any existing formula in that cell

Comment: Please can you help me with the VBA version? I am not conversant with VBA. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Chimezie, Unfortunately SuperUser is not a "Please write me a script" kind of service. We will help you figure out why a script is not working, but we will not write full VBA code for you. We will help with an excel formula though. Please see the Help Center to find out what kind of questions are on-topic here on SuperUser.

Answer (score 2):

> How do i write a formula that can provide answers to any field once the other two fields have been completed?

You CAN NOT.

Either you enter a formula or a constant (number) in a cell. You can not use the same cells to enter number in them once, and get them display a calculation next time.

As you've only 3 parameters it's easy to set up different ranges for calculation of the parameters.

Or just use a setup like below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mate, but i want a situation where by i can replicate what i saw on a website page: I do not want to have to visit the web page whenever i need to compute an item. 
 https://www.omnicalculator.com/business/commission

Comment: You could easily make the output copy the input field if its already given. That would at least make it uniform.

Comment: could you explain better?

Comment: @chimezieoleka "but i want a situation where by i can replicate what i saw on a website page" - that's where my first sentence is relevant: "not possible"

Answer (score 2):

Say we begin with:

[image]

So **A1** and **B1** have constants and **C1** has the formula.  Place this event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range, B As Range, C As Range, AC As Range

    Set A = Range("A1")
    Set B = Range("B1")
    Set C = Range("C1")
    Set AC = Union(A, B, C)

    With Application
        If Intersect(AC, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        If .WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(AC) <> 1 Then Exit Sub
        .EnableEvents = False
            If A = "" Then
                A = C / B
            ElseIf B = "" Then
                B = C / A
            Else
                C = A * B
            End If
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Then clear **A1** through **C1** *(as a block)*.
Then enter any two values.

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Hello Gary, i used the code and encountered the following error:

Comment: Compile Error: Syntax error. what could be the problem?